# IndexOutOfRangeException when trying to access the generic arguments of a Func<object> delegate

Tags: c#, .net, generics, reflection

I need to get the generic argument type from a factory delegate (`Func<object`), but it always results in a `IndexOutOfRangeException`.

```
public void Bind(Type service, Func<object> factory) {
    var factoryResultType = factory.Method.GetGenericArguments()[0]; // ex
}

// extension
public static void Bind<TService>(this IBinder binder, Func<TService> factory)
    where TService : class 
{
    binder.Bind(typeof(TService), (Func<object>) factory);
}

// usage
var dummyClass = new DummyClass();
binder.Bind<IDummy>(() => dummyClass);
```

Comment: What is the answer you expect in this case?

Comment: @SriramSakthivel The unboxed type of the delegate that has been passed, e.g. "DummyClass" in the example above.

Comment: You can't get the `DummyClass`. That type information is lost. You need to invoke the delegate to find the return value is `DummyClass`. OTOH you can get `IDummy` by `factory.GetType().GetGenericArguments()[0];`

Comment: @SriramSakthivel Is there a way to preserve the information? The binder currently binds the factory delegate to a interface (passed as generic), but what when I need to create the factory dynamically? Is there a different way of passing a delegate that preserves the information of having a return parameter (compared to an action delegate) that can be stored e.g. in a dictionary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A delegate `Func<T>` is compiled to something along these lines:

```
public class Func<T>
{
    public T Invoke() { /* ... */ }
}
```

The `MethodInfo` returned by `factory.Method` represents the `Invoke` method above. As you can see, this method is *not* generic, and that's why your code fails.

You could, instead, check its return type:

```
var type = f.Method.ReturnType;
```

Or, as @sszarek suggested, check the *type*'s generic arguments.

Comment: I think that your idea of using f.Method.ReturnType is way better. It is more straight forward.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your code right you want to get type provided when calling:

```
binder.Bind<IDummy>(() => dummyClass);
```

which is IDummy.
If that so: in your Bind method use this code:

```
 var factoryResultType = factory.GetType().GetGenericArguments()[0];
```

Method property of Func delegate will return MethodInfo for method which is not generic method. But the one that returns one specific type.
You can only get generic argument from Func delegate itself.